# How is printf() an expression?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, rvalue, lvalue

I was trying to learn value categories because of an error that I got and stared watching [this video by Copper Spice](https://youtu.be/wkWtRDrjEH4).

They go on to define an expression and as an example provide `printf()` [at this point in the video](https://youtu.be/wkWtRDrjEH4?t=51) (screenshot below).

[image: screenshot with printf]

How is [`printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) an expression? I always thought that function calls aren't really an expression when written by themselves. They are more like statements as my beginner mind thinks of it. Moreover, the definition they provide mentions **operators** and **operands** but none can be seen with `printf`. What am I missing?

The data type that is mentioned is the return value for `printf`. What about functions that return void?

Comment: `int x = 2 + 3;` contains the expression `2 + 3` that evaluates to `5`.  `int x = 2 + printf("hello");` contains the expression `2 + printf("hello")` that evaluates to `7` (aka `2` plus the value returned by `printf("hello")` which is almost certainly `5` in this case)

Comment: "when written by themselves": The confusion might be that e.g. `printf();` is a _statement_, more specifically an _expression statement_, meaning a statement that it just made up of one _expression_, namely `printf()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is printf() an expression?

It's a function call expression.

> I always that that function calls aren't really an expression

Function calls are expressions.

> They are more like statements

Function calls are not statements. Consider for example `ret = printf();`. Here, the function call is a subexpression of the assignment expression. Statements cannot be sub expressions - expressions can be sub expressions.

> Moreover, the definition they provide mentions operators and operands but none can be seen with printf.

The parentheses are the function call operator. The operands are the function (which is a postfix expression) on the left side of the parentheses and the argument list within the parentheses.

> How is the expression characterized by a data type?

Every expression has a type. The type - along with the value category - affects how you can use the expression.

> I thought that the data type was related to the return type of the printf function

You thought right. The type of a function call expression is determined by the return type of the function. The type of `printf()` is `int`.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the `&` operator can be applied to functions.

Comment: plus1. Could you add to answer what statements are then to clarify?

Comment: And do you mean that the operand is the text `printf` and an empty argument list?

Comment: @heretoinfinity The expression `printf`, and the empty parameter list are operands, yes.

Comment: To clarify, does the return type have nothing to do with the definition of an expression?

Comment: @heretoinfinity What do you mean by "definition of an expression"?

Comment: The definition as provided by the screen shot and the 2 factors mentioned in bullet points later on. How is the expression characterized by a **data type**? Initially, I thought that the data type was related to the return type of the `printf` function but your explanation of how `printf` is an expression had no mention of the return type.  I edited the question but I think the edit didn't show up before you posted an answer.

Comment: @heretoinfinity See latest edit.

Comment: @heretoinfinity "characterized by" does not mean "defined by". The two points are properties that every expression has, but what an expression is is (vaguely) defined in the bullet point above that.

Comment: @eerorika, what is your comment to Dan O's request?

Comment: @heretoinfinity I don't think it's relevant to the question.